# Clientside validation fails for date format dd/mm/yyyy in jQuery Validate

Tags: jquery-validate, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using jQuery Validate plugin for clientside validation in an MVC 5 application. For the date fields cilentside validations fails when using dd/mm/yyyy format. Is there a way to change the date format in jQuery Validation?

Answer (score 16):

Adding to Darin's answer. If you happen to already be using the datepicker plugin from JQuery UI then you can use that date parser instead of creating your own:

```
$.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) ||  $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value);
}
```

Comment: Ohh man.. It work fine for me.. I wasted almost a day to fix this..
Thanks

Comment: This seems to fix the problem for me but it breaks/disconnects all other javascript. Maybe I'm using the code above incorrectly? I simply included it upon document ready. Many thanks

Comment: @Charly Thanks.Works for me finally

Answer (score 4):

You could override the `date` parsing method of the validate plugin:

```
$.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || parseDate(value, "yyyy-MM-dd") !== null;
}
```

Here `parseDate` is a function that you could write yourself. The [`following thread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476105/how-can-i-convert-string-to-datetime-with-format-specification-in-javascript) might give you some ideas. Or use some existing plugin such as [`datejs`](http://www.datejs.com/) or [`Globalize`](https://github.com/jquery/globalize).