# jQuery validation for dates in dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, date

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 project. I have two text boxes in a view like so ...

```
@Html.TextBox("earliestDate", Model.Checklists.EarliestDate)
@Html.TextBox("latestDate", Model.Checklists.LatestDate)
```

I'm entering the dates "01/03/2014" (1st March 2014) and "31/03/2014" (31st March 2014). When I place a breakpoint in the controller, I can see that in the controller earliestDate has the value "03/01/2014" (the day and month I entered have been swapped around) while latestDate is null. The code works as desired if I enter the dates in yyyy-MM-dd format.

I followed the advice in [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view) article.

I have installed "globalize.js" and added the code from the article to my view. Nothing changed, I still got the results described above. So I tried modifying the code to specify the desired culture explicitly like so, old code commented out, my new code beneath it ...

```
@*<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/cultures/globalize.culture.@(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name).js"></script>*@
<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/cultures/globalize.culture.en-IE.js"></script>
```

and ...

```
//Globalize.culture('@(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name)');
```

Globalize.culture('en-IE');

This still didn't make any difference. So I tried explicitly adding the desired format to the `validator.methods.date` function like so ...

```
$.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) ||
        Globalize.parseDate(value) ||
        Globalize.parseDate(value, "dd-MM-yyyy") || // new code
        Globalize.parseDate(value, "yyyy-MM-dd");
}
```

Still no difference. What am I missing?

For reference, here is the complete script section from the view including the above modifications ...

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script src="~/Scripts/globalize/globalize.js"></script>
    @*<script src="~/Scripts/globalize/cultures/globalize.culture.@(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name).js"></script>*@
    <script src="~/Scripts/globalize/cultures/globalize.culture.en-IE.js"></script>
    <script>
    $.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) ||
            !isNaN(Globalize.parseFloat(value));
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Globalize.culture('@(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name)');
        Globalize.culture('en-IE');
    });
    </script>
    <script>
        jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.methods, {
            range: function (value, element, param) {
                //Use the Globalization plugin to parse the value
                var val = Globalize.parseFloat(value);
                return this.optional(element) || (
                    val >= param[0] && val <= param[1]);
            }
        });
        $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) ||
                Globalize.parseDate(value) ||
                Globalize.parseDate(value, "dd/MM/yyyy") || // new code
                Globalize.parseDate(value, "yyyy-MM-dd");
        }
    </script>
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856019/clientside-validation-fails-for-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-in-jquery-validate you can find your answer same question here also.

Answer (score 0):

What is in your jQueryval Bundle?

I'd have the same problem and I solve it adding the script `~/Scripts/globalize/globalize.js`

This script solves the date problem but add a new problem with number validation. 
Without this script, date validation is wrong and number validation ok...

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but if you will look a little more carefully at my question, and at the article referenced, you will see that I have already tried that.